PyMuPDF page.insert_textbox doen't work properly
I'm writing a pdf translator using python. I use page.add_redact_annot(blk[:4]) and page.apply_redactions() to delete the original text block, and use page.insert_textbox to insert translated text to the position where the original block is at. But it seems that not all page.insert_textbox calls write the text block successfully. I run my program multiple times, get different results (ignore translation differences, I'm sure that all text is translated):

Here is the code:
import os
import fitz
from translator import Translator


def dec_to_rgb_float(dec):
    hex_val = format(dec, "06x")
    r = int(hex_val[0:2], 16)
    g = int(hex_val[2:4], 16)
    b = int(hex_val[4:6], 16)
    return round(r / 255, 4), round(g / 255, 4), round(b / 255, 4)


class PDFHandler:
    def __init__(self, translator: Translator):
        self.translator = translator

    def handle(self, input_file: str, output_file=None):
        if not os.path.exists(input_file):
            raise FileNotFoundError("File does not exist: {}".format(input_file))
        self.input_file = input_file
        self.output_file = output_file
        if self.output_file == None:
            self.output_file = os.path.join(
                os.path.dirname(input_file),
                "translated_" + os.path.basename(input_file),
            )
        self.__handle()

    def __handle(self):
        doc = fitz.open(self.input_file)
        # try:
        for i, page in enumerate(doc):
            print(f"Translating page {i+1}: ", end="")
            blks = page.get_text("blocks")
            blks = [blk for blk in blks if blk[6] != 1]
            new_blks = []
            for j, blk in enumerate(blks):
                style = page.get_text("dict", flags=11)["blocks"][blk[5]]["lines"][0][
                    "spans"
                ][0]
                new_blks.append({})
                new_blks[-1]["fontsize"] = style["size"]
                new_blks[-1]["rect"] = blk[:4]
                new_blks[-1]["color"] = dec_to_rgb_float(style["color"])
                new_blks[-1]["text"] = blk[4].strip()
                page.add_redact_annot(blk[:4])
            page.apply_redactions()

            for j, new_blk in enumerate(new_blks):
                print(f"{j+1}/{len(blks)}", end=" ", flush=True)
                text = self.translator.translate(new_blk["text"])
                page.insert_textbox(
                    new_blk["rect"],
                    buffer=text,
                    fontsize=new_blk["fontsize"],
                    color=new_blk["color"],
                    fontname="MiSans",
                    fontfile="./fonts/MiSans-Regular.ttf",
                )
            if page.is_wrapped:
                print("Page is wrapped.")
            else:
                print("Page is not wrapped.")
            print("")
        # except Exception as error:
        #     print("Exception:\n", error)
        #     return
        while os.path.exists(self.output_file):
            print("The output file already exists.")
            self.output_file = input("New path: ").strip()
            if len(self.output_file) == 0:
                print("Ignore output.")
                return
        doc.save(self.output_file, garbage=3, deflate=True)


I find out the return value of insert_textbox indicates if the call is successful. Now I just retry with smaller font size.

Ah, I see you have noticed your error. I recommend to not use insert_textbox() in your case. Instead take page.insert_htmlbox(). This is able to automatically shrink the content to force-fit into the rectangle. Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.

@JorjMcKie Yes, now I'm using insert_htmlbox. It's much more powerful. insert_textbox() can't wrap line for CJK characters.
